# Jackson Java 8 DateTime serialisation

Tags: timestamp, java-8, milliseconds, java-time, jackson-modules

Jackson operates java.time.Instant with `WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS` (`READ_` as well) enabled by default. 
[jackson-datatype-jsr310](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310)

It produces JSON like this

`{ "createDate":1421261297.356000000, "modifyDate":1421261297.356000000 }`

In JavaScript it's much easier to get Date from traditional millis timestamp (not from seconds/nanos as above), like `new Date(1421261297356)`.

I think there should be some reason to have the nanos approach by default, so what is that reason?

Comment: The reason is probably that Jackson tries not to lose the precision the Instant has. The receiver might not be JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, most likely you right. But nonos are really zeros here. Perhaps this is more to Java 8 java.time.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to create your own Jackson module and do the serialization you way need.

You can even do a simple Jackson8Module which extends the Jackson SimpleModule and provides some lambda friendly methods.

```
ObjectMapper jacksonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Jackson8Module module = new Jackson8Module();
module.addStringSerializer(LocalDate.class, (val) -> val.toString());
module.addStringSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, (val) -> val.toString());
jacksonMapper.registerModule(module);
```

Here is the code for the Jackson8Module:

[Is there a way to use Java 8 lambda style to add custom Jackson serializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156789/is-there-a-way-to-use-java-8-lambda-style-to-add-custom-jackson-serializer)

Answer (score 5):

I have found this weird to, since using JSR310Module classes like Calendar or Date are still serialized in milliseconds. It's not logical.

In the JSR310Module documentation (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310) they have a referenced this:

> For serialization, timestamps are written as fractional numbers (decimals), where the number is seconds and the decimal is fractional seconds, if WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS is enabled (it is by default), with resolution as fine as nanoseconds depending on the underlying JDK implementation. If WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS is disabled, timestamps are written as a whole number of milliseconds.

So, a simple solution for what you want to achieve it's configure your mapper like they say:

```
  mapper.configure( SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false );
  mapper.configure( SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true );
```

Comment: `WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS` is really confusing name because what it really does: it writes timestamps as SECONDS (not NANOSECONDS) with fractional part. And that fractional part contains up to 6 digits after dot, so it can be interpreted as NANOSECONDS part, but the whole value is still in seconds.

Comment: mapper.configure()  - where should this be done? Do you know how to do this in XML?