# LocalDateTime not serialized as a timestamp

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using `jackson-datatype-jsr310` to support Java 8 time data types.

I created a ObjectMapper like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

Foo foo = new Foo();
LocalDateTime t = LocalDateTime.now();
foo.setT1(Date.from(t.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)));
foo.setT2(Timestamp.valueOf(t));
foo.setT3(t);

System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(foo));
```

And parsed a LocalDateTime then I got `[2016,12,21,15,53,57,178]` not `1482306837178`

Here is my test model class `Foo`

```
public class Foo {

    private Date t1;

    private Timestamp t2;

    private LocalDateTime t3;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

I see the question [Jackson Java 8 DateTime serialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951124/jackson-java-8-datetime-serialisation) and the problem owner get a serialized string like `1421261297.356000000`. I did't known how to get that. I'm using jackson 2.8.5 same with `datatype-jsr310`.

Comment: Where does `BigDecimal` come in here?

Comment: Sorry for my typo. @shmosel

Comment: What was the full output of `println()`?

Comment: `{"t1":1482335637178,"t2":1482306837178,"t3":[2016,12,21,15,53,57,178]}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Jackson Modules Datetime documentation:

> LocalDate, LocalTime, LocalDateTime, and OffsetTime, which cannot portably be converted to timestamps and are instead represented as arrays when WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS is enabled.

Full doc page [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime)